# Making equations

Tags: linear-algebra

A plant is growing on the surface of the pond. Hank noticed the plant on Day 1. Two days later Hank was worried about the plant and started measuring the area that the plant covered.

The plant followed the same pattern of growth.

```
                           Day 1       Area covered by plant

                               1                   1
       '
                               2                   2
                               3                   4                       
                               4                   8
                               5                   16
                               6                   32
                               7                   64
                               8                   128
```

Write an equation from this table

I did:

1  2  4  8  16  32  64  128

```
 1 2 4 8 16 32 64
  1 2 4 8 16 32
```

I've done this but I can't find the answer.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't recognize the numbers in the second column as powers of two, ask [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+8%2C+16%2C+32%2C+64).

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ be the day and $a$ the area of the plant. $a$ doubles every day, meaning this is our equation:

$$2^{d-1}=a$$